# Batch column search / replace user input

Tags: batch-file

I need to get a batch file running, which helps our employees to change text files without trouble.

[image]

As you can see, there are a lot of whit space in this file and they need to be there, otherwise it could not be imported in other programs.

My question: Is it possible to search for a specific column and replace this value with an user input?

I've tried to get something done with help of google and this was the result:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in (Muster.dat) do set "var=%%a"&goto :done
:done
set "R_sph=%var:~126,5%"
echo R_sph: %R_sph%

set /p R_sph_new=Enter new sph:
echo R_sph neu: %R_sph_new%

set "search=R_sph"
set "replace=R_sph_new"
set "textfile=Muster.dat"
set "newfile=Muster2.dat"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"

del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
pause
```

PS: My batch experience is worse and it would be great to explain every step in the code you send me.

Edit: We generate a lot of files like this every day and only some of them need so be edited. The construction of this files is always the same but with other values so it's important so search via column.

Comment: The `skip=5` means you read the 6th line, which just contains a single character, "0". Then you've got `R_sph=%var:~126,5%` which takes five characters starting from the 126th, which doesn't exist and doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This screenshot is from notepad++, please have a look at the left side of the picture, there is the line number. One line of this file is really long and because of this it looks like that.

Comment: Does your current batch file not work? I couldn't find anything seriously wrong with it after a brief look.

Comment: It's working but all same values will change when it's running, it should just change the value from line 6 and 5 characters from the 126th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the main loop in your batch file so that:

1. it only changes the 6th line;
2. it only changes the 5 characters from position 126 to 130.

And just to make the batch script more robust, you can also validate user input to ensure that they've entered exactly 5 characters as the replacement string.

Here's the whole file with suggested changes:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in (Muster.dat) do set "var=%%a"&goto :done
:done
set "R_sph=%var:~126,5%"
echo R_sph: %R_sph%

set /p R_sph_new=Enter new sph:
echo R_sph neu: %R_sph_new%

rem Validate user input - ensure it's exactly 5 characters
set "replace=%R_sph_new%     "
set "replace=%replace:~0,5%"
if not "%R_sph_new%" == "%replace%" (
    echo Don't be silly.
    exit /b 1
)

set "textfile=Muster.dat"
set "newfile=Muster2.dat"

set /a lineNumber = 0
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set /a lineNumber += 1
    set "line=%%i"
    if !lineNumber! == 6 set "line=!line:~0,126!%replace%!line:~131!"
    echo(!line!
))>"%newfile%"

rem It might be safer to rename %textfile% to %textfile%.BAK instead of deleting it.
del %textfile%
rename %newfile% %textfile%

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: I've tried the second code and it works if the user insert a string which is too long but what's about a too short one?

Comment: The `set "replace=%R_sph_new%     "` adds 5 spaces at the end of the input string, and then the following line truncates it to 5 characters. If the input string was too short, it won't be equal to the "replace" variable.

Comment: That's true but if I just enter the value 2 for example, the hole value of `R_sph` will be replaced by the value 2

Comment: If the user enters "2", then the line `set "replace=%R_sph_new%     "` will be scanned as `set "replace=2     "`. So after the truncation performed on the next line, the variable `replace` will have the value "2    ". That's "2" followed by four spaces. If that's what you want, you can use that. Otherwise, my example code compares "2    " to the original "2" and since they differ, it gets thrown out.

Comment: I got it, just need to replace `replace` by `R_sph` in `if not "%R_sph_new%" == "%replace%"`

Comment: No, it should stay as it is. `R_sph` is the original from the file. What you need to compare is the user input (`R_sph_new`) with `replace` which is the "cleaned up" user input. In other words, that line has nothing to do with the contents of the file but is there just to validate user input.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the full batch file incorporating my suggested changes. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: My fault was maybe here: `set "replace=%R_sph_new%     "` because I missed the 5 wihte spaces after `new%`, now it's working fine. The rename or edleting will be changed as soon as I kknow the real file name and where it needs to be safed.

Comment: I have another question, because now I need to replace the same value on two different lines. The value is on the exact same place in both lines.

Comment: @Patrick unfortunately the `if` command doesn't have an `or` operator so you can't say `if !lineNumber! == 6 or !lineNumber! == 7 set "line=!line:~0,126!%replace%!line:~131!"` You have to repeat the whole line and add `if !lineNumber! == 8 ...` unless someone else reading this knows of a neater solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, there is no need to simplify this.

Comment: I've tried different things to change the filename in a not specific name. That's because we have a lot of different named files we need to change, so we just copy this files in a new folder and there I want to run this batch file to change the values.  `for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in (Muster.dat) do set "var=%%a"&goto :done` if I try to change `Muster.dat` into `*.dat` he can't find the file even if I paste in the whole path...

Comment: `for /f` doesn't take wildcards, even though other forms of `for` do. You should put your batch commands in a subroutine by adding label `:process` at the top, and then put above it: `for %f in (*) do call process %f`. Then in the subroutine, refer to the file as parameter `%1`. Put `exit /b` after this top-level loop to avoid falling into the :process subroutine when the loop finishes.

Comment: It's working now, I forgot to set `%` in front of `%f` for batch file. But I'm not sure how `exit /b` does work here?

Comment: Ah yes, that should have been `for %%f` (double %% in batch files, single % when typed interactively on the command line). The `exit /b` (same thing as `goto :eof`) exits the batch file. The idea is that when you finish processing all your files, you want to exit the batch file. Without `exit /b`, the processing would continue to the remaining lines of the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "search=R_sph"
set "replace=R_sph_new"
```

should

```
set "search=%R_sph%"
set "replace=%R_sph_new%"
```

that is, set the values of `search` and `replace` to the **contents of** the variables. Your code sets `search` to the **string** `R_sph`.

? Are you sure that the value in `R_sph` will be unique in your file?

Comment: Thank you, I solved this problem by myself. the value in `R_sph` won't be unique. Sometimes this value exist 3 or 4 times and I also want to replace some other values not only this one, but in a next step.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Klitos Kyriacou, that's exactly what I was looking for!
But unfortunately this batch does not change anything in this text file, the whole code looks like this:

```
@echo off
:R_sph
for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in (Muster.dat) do set "var=%%a"&goto :done
:done
set "R_sph=%var:~49,5%"
echo R_sph: %R_sph%

set /p R_sph_new=Enter new sph:
set "replace=%R_sph_new%"
set "textfile=Muster.dat"
set "newfile=Muster2.dat"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a lineNumber = 0
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set /a lineNumber += 1
    set "line=%%i"
    if !lineNumber! == 6 set "line=!line:~0,49!%replace%!line:~54!"
    echo(!line!
))>"%newfile%"
endlocal

:replace file
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
pause
```

Edit: I was in hurry and dind't get how to set it up. Now I changed the code and it's working!